# How to resolve static reference error when implementing ActionListener for Java Swing elements?

Tags: java, swing

I am a fairly novice Java programmer who is trying to create a simple user interface using java swing elements that accepts user input and (eventually among other things) validates that the entered date is in the correct format.

I am currently trying to use a main "createTextbox" class that makes the form along with a class that implements ActionListener to read the user's input and validate the date when a button is clicked.  The problem I'm having is that when I try in the ActionListener class to reference my fields from CreateTextbox, I get an error since my fields are non-static being referenced in a static context.  However I don't want to define the fields as static since I want the user to be able to change the input and click the button again.

Here is my CreateTextbox class:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class CreateTextbox extends JFrame{

  JTextField stringEntry, dateEntry;
  JLabel stringEntryLabel, dateEntryLabel;
  JButton print;


  public CreateTextbox(){

    setLayout(null);
    stringEntry = new JTextField(1);
    stringEntry.setBounds(100,20,100,20);
    add(stringEntry);

    stringEntryLabel = new JLabel("String Name:");
    stringEntryLabel.setBounds(10,20,100,20);
    add(stringEntryLabel);

    dateEntry = new JTextField(1);
    dateEntry.setBounds(100,50,100,20);
    add(dateEntry);

    dateEntryLabel = new JLabel("Date:");
    dateEntryLabel.setBounds(10,50,100,20);

    print = new JButton("Validate");
    print.setBounds(20,260,100,20);
    print.addActionListener(new MyAction());
    add(print);

  }

  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    CreateTextbox me = new CreateTextbox();
    me.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    me.setVisible(true);
    me.setLocation(550, 500);
    me.setSize(700, 700);
    me. setTitle("Create Textbox");

  }

}
```

And the ActionListener class:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.ParseException;

public class MyAction implements ActionListener {

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String strInput = CreateTextbox.stringEntry.getText();
    String strDate = CreateTextbox.dateEntry.getText();
    valiDate(strDate);
  }
  public void valiDate(String date) {
    //code to validate the date
  }
}
```

I'm guessing this has a pretty simple solution that I'm overlooking.  I've looked at several posts like [Non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559527/non-static-variable-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context), but am still having trouble wrapping my head around a solution for this.

Comment: Give MyAction a constructor that takes a CreateTextbox parameter and pass `this` into it. Then make method calls as needed. Fields should be private, not public, and only accessible through public methods.

Comment: Pass the instance of CreateTextbox to the constructor of your listener. Or make the listener an inner class, to be able to reference its outer instance fields directly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559527/non-static-variable-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context)

Comment: Probably an inner class makes sense here.

Comment: Of utmost importance though is that this error suggests that your Java foundational knowledge needs another brick -- you must study on what static and instance means and how this applies to Java programming, since this key bit of knowledge is absolutely necessary for you to progress. Check the tutorials and your books and study this deeply. You won't regret doing this.

Comment: Yep, I'm trying to learn!  Thanks for your concern, DontKnowMuchBut Getting Better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've stated you're learning, I'm goign to try to give you a didactical answer with the "whys and why-nots", maybe a bit too long but hope it helps you.

When you refer to `CreateTextbox.stringEntry` you're referring a class variable, this is, an static one because you're actually telling in the first part of the statement a class, not an object, and that is common to all the instances of that class.

On the other hand when you do `this.stringEntry` you're refererring the variable of an object which is different from `that.stringEntry` and they're property of their owner objects. It must be said that in general it's a bad practice (of course there's times when it's reasonable not to do it so) to let your variables visible, but instead let others access them by "getters", methods that give you access to the inner variable: `getStringEntry():JTextField`, `getDateEntry():JTextField`. But again, you don't want to let others get your components because they can be manipulated from outside when you just want to expose their values, so just instead expose their respective texts:

```
public String getNameText() {
    return this.stringEntry.getText();
}

public String getDateText() {
    return this.dateEntry.getText();
}
```

Then, you have an `ActionListener` in another class. When the event of the `ActionListener` is triggered the method receives an `ActionEvent` which contains a reference to the object that originates the event and can be accessed through the method `getSource()`. When you have an outer class you're expecting to use that class "attached" to the `CreateTextbox` and so you'd be expecting to receive the `CreateTextbox` in the source and so you'd have access to the instance like this:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object source = e.getSource();
    if (source instanceof CreateTextbox) {
        CreateTextbox instance = (CreateTextbox) source;
        String strInput = instance.getNameText();
        String strDate = instance.getDateText();
        valiDate(strDate);
    }
}
```

Note that you're now accessing the object (one single instantiation of the class), not the class statically (common across all the instances).

But you're adding this action to a button, so you'll receive a `JButton` as a source, which is an inner component of what you're implementing so this should lead you to think you'd better be using an inner class. *Please, note that this is not generally true nor necessary, I'm talking from a good design point of view, you can indeed implement this in outer classes.* Let me add a recommendation to use `Action` instead of `ActionListener`, it's not a big difference but it's useful because it encapsulates the whole action to be used by different components and make it available across a hierarchy of components aswell as names, icons and such.

Once moved to inside the class you have the option to declare the inner class `static` and making it independent of the instance; or not, so you can access the variables. Obviously yours is the second case.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String strInput = CreateTextbox.this.stringEntry.getText();
    String strDate = CreateTextbox.this.dateEntry.getText();
    valiDate(strDate);
}
```

This is how your method would look like in an inner class, reverting to your original code but noting that your original `CreateTextbox.stringEntry` (static reference) is now `CreateTextbox.this.stringEntry` (accessing to the instance).

Finally this is how it could look like:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CreateTextbox extends JFrame {

    /* Make your inner components private, it's your responsibility to manage
     * them and so you'd not get undesired interactions */
    protected JTextField stringEntry, dateEntry;
    protected JLabel stringEntryLabel, dateEntryLabel;
    protected JButton print;
    protected Action validateAction;

    public CreateTextbox() {
        super("Create Textbox"); // The title makes more sense in the constructor
        /* Never use a null layout, is a bad practice, can work for a one-shot
         * but is in no way something you can manage or expand. Also the results
         * are usually clunky. I use MigLayout, it requires expertise but when
         * you master it it's very useful. For standard ones:
         * https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html */
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new MigLayout("ins 10, gap 5", // Margin around of 10 px
                                                 // 5px between components 
                "[][grow]", // Fist column, minimum; second column, grow
                "[][][]"));

        /* "this." is not necessary but it's good to realize we're talking about
         * the variable of this INSTANCE of the class */
        this.stringEntryLabel = new JLabel("Name:");
        add(this.stringEntryLabel, ""); // This string is the constraint for telling
                                   // MigLayout how to place this component,
                                   // nothing required in this case 

        this.stringEntry = new JTextField();
        add(this.stringEntry, "grow, wrap"); // Fill space, next line

        this.dateEntryLabel = new JLabel("Date:");
        add(this.dateEntryLabel, "");

        this.dateEntry = new JTextField();
        add(this.dateEntry, "grow, wrap");

        this.validateAction = new MyAction();

        this.print = new JButton(this.validateAction); // Button for the action
        add(this.print, "span 2, center"); // Use 2 cells, center the button

        /* Example of how it's useful to have an action, not just a listener */
        getRootPane().getActionMap().put("validate", this.validateAction);
    }

    /* Added originally for didactical purposes */
    @Deprecated
    public String getNameText() {
        return this.stringEntry.getText();
    }

    /* Added originally for didactical purposes */
    @Deprecated
    public String getDateText() {
        return this.dateEntry.getText();
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        CreateTextbox me = new CreateTextbox();
        me.pack(); // Since now you have a layout, let it do its thing
        me.setLocationByPlatform(true); // Let OS place the window
        me.setVisible(true);
    }


    /* MyAction is better an Action than an ActionListener to it can be used for
     * more purposes */
    public class MyAction extends AbstractAction {

        public MyAction() {
            super("Validate");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String strInput = CreateTextbox.this.stringEntry.getText();
            String strDate = CreateTextbox.this.dateEntry.getText();
            valiDate(strDate);
        }

        public void valiDate(String date) {
            // TODO code to validate the date
            System.out.println("Validating date \"" + date + "\"...");
        }

    }

}
```

Just let me add that you should have a look at the article ["How to Use Formatted Text Fields"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html), because Java already has its own ways to validate dates and other values from text fields.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I believe understood why the error was happening in that I was trying reference a non-static field from a static context, but I was one step away from following the this.stringEntry answer until reading your explanation.

Thans so much for taking the time to write all this out.

Answer (score 0):

I would inline the listener class. That way you can access the instance variables, even if they're private.

```
print.addActionListener(event -> {
  String strInput = CreateTextbox.stringEntry.getText();
  String strDate = CreateTextbox.dateEntry.getText();
  validate(strDate);
});
```